# How to UPDATE all ColX with string+ColY data+string

Tags: mysql

I'm struggling with the simplest (seemingly) of MySQL updates. I have this structure:

```
Col1   Col2   Col3
1      "A"    null
2      "B"    null
etc...
```

I have thousands of rows to update with this serialized data: a:1:{i:0;s:7:"[contents of Col3].png";}

I've tried:

```
UPDATE Blaa SET Col3 = "a:1:{i:0;s:7:\""Col2".png\";}";
UPDATE Blaa SET Col3 = "a:1:{i:0;s:7:\""&Col2&".png\";}";
UPDATE Blaa SET Col3 = "a:1:{i:0;s:7:\""+Col2+".png\";}";
```

and loads more variations on that theme.. I think I might need a 'select' in there but I dont know how to make it target the current row.

I need the final table to have this data:

```
Col1   Col2   Col3
1      "A"    "a:1:{i:0;s:5:"A.png";}"
2      "B"    "a:1:{i:0;s:5:"B.png";}"
etc...
```

Tired... hungry... confused... deadline just sailed past on the left. Help! *flop*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you need a change in schema, not a change in query :).  But anyway, you're looking for the function CONCAT.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html

Comment: Ok thanks Corbin. That was exactly what I needed. Here's the query I ended up with, with added 'length' function so the serialized data isn't broken if Col3 is longer or shorter than expected: `UPDATE Blaa SET Col3 = CONCAT( 'a:1:{i:0;s:',length(Col2)+4,':"',Col2,'.png";}')`

Answer (score 1):

```
update table_name
set col3 = concat('"a:1:{i:0;s:5:"',replace(col2,'"',''),'.png";}"');
```